# How to inflate compound view x amount of times

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

In my app im coding I need a compound view I created to be inflated X amount of times based off the answer provided from last Activity (AKA dynamic Inflation of the Compound View based off user's input) I searched all around and couldn't find a solid answer.

Again how could I inflate my custom compound view x amount of times based off the number the user entered!

Here's what my compound view looks like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGrsj.png)

Comment: If you use inflate more than one, it is inflating more than one! just remember to change the values each time you inflate.

Answer (score 0):

First it has to be clear what you are doing,  like are you repeating the custom view more then once based on the input from the previous activity or you just want to change the values of the textviews in the layout. 
Any ways You can store the answer from the previous activity in a bundle and use a for loop to inflate the data based on the value in the bundle.

Comment: okay thanks ill try to attempt inflating and update my post with my for loop to see if im doing correctly

Comment: Guys im still attemtping to make the for loop, If i cant fully do it ill edit here in less than a day for more help, then Ill award you the answers credits for helping